# Pandas dataframe, max of selection

Tags: python, pandas

[image: I have a pandas dataframe with following columns:]

I need to write a function, which takes df with data and returns string with country, which GDP is maximum among countries with area(sq km) is less than 200 OR which population is less than 1000.

How to write this code correctly?

```
def find_country(df):
    df.loc[((df.Area < 200).Max(df.GDP))|(df.Population < 1000)]
```

Comment: Please provide a full sample dataframe to work with.

Comment: @FabioLamanna I edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make your first column to be your Index. This could be done using the following command:

```
df.set_index('Country', inlace = True)
```

Assuming you want to replace your dataframe with the reworked version.
To find your desired country you simply look for the date which has the maximum GDP, for instance, and return its index. The subscript of the index is needed to get the actual value of the index.

```
def find_Country(df):
    return df[df['GDP'] == max(df['GDP'])].index[0]
```

I hope this will help,
Fabian